# Deactivate automatic debugging for certain application under WinXP and Win7-32

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, c#

I have asked a question about handling crashes of a command line tool in a C# application on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4799660/can-i-catch-appcrash-of-command-line-app-launched-with-cs-system-diagnostic-pro). I was pointed to this forum for finding out, how to avoid that WerFault.exe jumps in and displays a crash report message for the command line tool, the crash of which I want to handle with my C# application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Crashes are handled by Windows by default, [visit Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com) for a programmatic solution to hook into the process instead of waiting for a capture. But, you might not need to hook yourself:

Windows looks up

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AeDebug
```

in order to know what debugger needs to be launched when a crass occurs.

The most usual generators are:

- [Dr. Watson](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc939482.aspx)
- [ProcDump](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/dd996900)

The most usual debuggers are:

- [Visual Studio Debugger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sc65sadd.aspx)
- [WinDBG](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/devtools/debugging/default.mspx)

Of these, you might be able to just let **Dr. Watson** or **ProcDump** do it's job,
after which you can open the debugging file for more information. These three links might get you going if you need to read the generated `*.dmp` files they produce:

- [Debug Help Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679309(v=VS.85).aspx)
- [Image Help Libarry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680321(v=VS.85).aspx)

Even better, you might be able to just use [ProcDump](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/dd996900) and don't even need to set `AeDebug\Debugger`.

Comment: Thanks! Apparently automatic debugging can be deactivated for certain applications under Windows versions newer than XP/Server 2003: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb204634%28v=vs.85%29.aspx For older OS versions there seems to be no chance.